# convert int to string with decimals

Tags: c, string, int, decimal

I want to write my own function in C for various reasons that converts an int to a string of decimals, just like sprintf.

Example:

```
    int number = 254;
    char string[10];
    sprintf(string, "%d", number);
```

The string should look like this after the function I want to write:

```
    [0] 2
    [1] 5
    [2] 4
    [3] '\0'
```

Just to clarify even further, I want to program the actual convertion of an int to a string of chars. I don't want to use sprintf or itoa etc to do it. I want to know how it is done and be able to program it myself and do small adjustments to it.

Additional clarification:
I don't want to use itoa or sprintf, but pretty much program these myself.

Comment: While it looks like C/C++, could you please tag the question correctly for the language used?

Comment: This question is highly language dependent. Do you mean in C?

Comment: Ah, forgot to mention the language, added it now, and it's C.

Comment: I know how to program in C... I don't need any help with that. I want to know how to do the convertion without using itoa or sprintf. <_<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int i2a(char *s, int n){
    div_t qr;
    int pos;

    if(n == 0) return 0;

    qr = div(n, 10);
    pos = i2a(s, qr.quot);
    s[pos] = qr.rem + '0';
    return pos + 1;
}

char* my_itoa(char *output_buff, int num){
    char *p = output_buff;
    if(num < 0){
        *p++ = '-';
        num *= -1;
    } else if(num == 0)
        *p++ = '0';
    p[i2a(p, num)]='\0';
    return output_buff;
}

int main(void){
    int number = -254;
    char string[12];
    printf("%s", my_itoa(string, number));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I take it this can handle signed ints too?

Comment: @CMan `can handle signed int too?` yes

Answer (score 0):

```
int number = 254;
int back=0,i=0;
char ch='\0';
char string[10];

for(i=0;(number/10)==0;i++){
    back=number%10;
    ch=(back*pow(10,i)+48);
    string[i]=ch;
}
```

1. divide number per 10
2. get the rest( with % ) the rest is the digit you want starting from the right
3. cast the digit to char +48(ascii 0)
4. add to string